# How can I overlay two images, where overlapping areas are a different color?

Tags: overlay, merge

So, my objective is this.

- ImageA is red/black and
- ImageB is blue/black.

They largely are similar but have different components. What I want to do is have it so that I can merge the two images and the non-overlapping red or blue are remaining as they are but the areas that align and overlap between the two images becomes purple.

Essentially it is so that the merger of the areas created is marked by a different color. I've read the **opencv** might be a good tool but I'm not sure. Is there a way to achieve this goal? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of what you mean?

Comment: So say i have to ImageA be a big yellow ball, ImageB be a small red ball; i want to merge them so that in the merged image where they overlap youll get an orange small ball, encompassed by a yellow area.

Comment: Have you attempted *anything* yourself? What software do you plan on using?? What's the nature of the images - raster or vector?

Comment: The first one who do not like you got an answer signed up. Insert some more information to the question to stop further downvotes to both of us and then read the answer from the edit log. That answer talks about using drawing- or image editing software. It's useless for selecting a good workhorse library for programming computer vision applications.

Comment: What software are you using?  Can you please provide an example image showing what you are trying to achieve, or what you have tried?  This question needs more details.

Comment: So your objective is clear, but what resources you actually have to use is not clear. Its not terribly useful if i tell you how to do it in app X if it only runs on OS Y and you have neither. Also if your question is on OpenCV then you are in the wrong place to ask. Generally this kind of action is also not entirely benefoixial in raster space as you will just blow up your antialiasation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good time to learn some basic capabilities of graphic software.

Different image layers and also separate items in vector drawing software (Inkscape, Illustrator) can have Blend Modes, which create color mixes in overlapping areas. Most users learn soon to apply them, often in much more advanced way than this:

[image]

The blue circle has blend mode difference. Blending obeys it's predefined math and it cannot be changed. But it's possible to make the overlapping areas as separate items or image layers and colorize them as needed:

[image]

In vector drawing programs one can easily duplicate items and make combinations. This is the intersection of the duplicates of the circle and rectangle and got green fill color. The combinations in Inkscape are "path operations". In Illustrator one uses Pathfinder or Shape Builder.

If you have the black components as separate items with normal blend mode, they are not at all affected by underlying things:

[image]

If the black areas are inseparable from the colored parts, the used blending mode affects also them. The result can be complex, maybe unwanted:

[image]

The blue circle and the B are together the top image layer (or as well a group of objects)  which has blending mode Difference.

Hopefully you read this soon, because long time writers here want to see something else than elementaries.

Comment: Hi Brad. Welcome to GDSE.  Sometimes it's better to wait for the OP to add more details before providing an answer.  The question as currently asked is missing quite a lot of detail, for example we don't even know at this stage if they are talking about a raster image or a vector image, or even what software they are using.

Comment: Yes sir!  I have fixed my answer to take it into the account.

Comment: Hi Brad. I have converted your edited answer to a comment and rolled back your answer. While it might not be a perfect answer, it did contain possible useful information. Your edit destroyed this info and was nothing more than a comment.  Please see the [Tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how Questions, Answers and Comments work on the Stack Exchange network.